# Create new project in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, project

In tutorials and in the programming book I am following, it all shows something like this to be on the homepage of vscode:
[image]

I want this too, so I can press the "Create a new project" button. However, my homepage of vscode looks like this, also after re-installing:
[image]

How can I create a new project?

Comment: MS  Visual Studio (aka "MSVS") <> Vlsual Studio Code.  Your book uses MSVS, you're using VSCode.  Q: What kind of "project"?  A C#/ASP.Net web app?  Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorials you're following are for [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio). You've installed [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code). Despite the similar names, they are completely separate products with completely different UI's and implementations, but with a little overlap in functionality. If you want the full Visual Studio (the current version of which is 2022), you probably qualify for the free Community edition, which you can download [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/), though of course you should double check the license to be sure.